# Firefox Scrolbar CSS issue

Tags: html, css

I have a site that has a CSS layout and shouldn't have a scrollbar appear:

http://souk.gumpshen.com/

But a scrollbar appears, I can't figure it out can anyone help please?

Comment: the scroll bar on the right for the user because the content is expanding down ?

Comment: Zoom out. The scrollbar becomes disabled but stays there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `height` in there is causing the scrollbar to appear.

```
.flower {
    background: url("../images/flowers.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 400px;
    left: 696px;
    position: relative;
    top: -360px;
    width: 400px;
    z-index: 101;
}
```

For what you're doing, change `top` to `margin-top` and it should fix it.

Comment: Thanks very much spent ages looking for that

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is on line `43` of `style.css`:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Change it to:

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix his problem when I remove it w/ Firebug.

Comment: On Chrome it did. I don't have FF installed.